# How can I display the progress for "git add"?

Tags: git

I have a bunch of files I need to add to git. But it takes a lot of time. Is there a way to display the progress bar?

Comment: `git add` should really not take a long time at all, it's been near-instantaneous every time I've used it. How immense are your files? Are you working on a network file system or something slow like that?

Comment: Also, *how* do you add files? Care to share your command?

Comment: I have over 100K files and this is for the initial git add. I used these command: git add .

Comment: Interesting - but even 100k files should `git add` within a minute or two, on most modern systems (spinning media might be significantly slower than SSD here). (If we expect 10 IOPs per file and 10k IOPS/s we get 1k files/s = 100 s or about 1.5 minutes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow.

The closest to a progress I can find is : the `--verbose | -v` option, which will print a line each time a file is added.

```
$ git add -v <lotoffiles>
add 'file1.txt'
add 'file2.txt'
...
```

---

As other comments suggested : `git add` is generally considered a quick command, and slowness may indicate that you are versioning very big files, or that the filesystem you work on is slow -- as in, for example, a network mounted drive.

If you want more help on what causes this slowness, you can edit your question to add more details on your particular use case.